# Git merge strategy for Agile Branching workflow

Tags: git, agile, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

We're adopting a new branching policy to work with Agile and to enable us to release on a feature by feature basis, whereby we have a `master` branch and a `QA` branch as perpetual branches. Nightly builds will be based on `QA` and releases will come from `master`. Developers will create a feature branch for each story.  All feature branches are to be branched off `master`, and then merged into `QA` for testing, followed by a merge of the feature branch into `master` for subsequent release. This is fine, until the following scenario:

- Developer A ("Rod") has created `feature/RodsFeature`, carried out some work and merged into `QA` (but not yet `master`)
- Developer B ("Jane") has created `feature/JanesFeature`, carried out some work and is now attempting to merge into `QA`
- Merge conflicts are now occurring for Jane, caused by changes introduced to `QA` by Rod's merge of `feature/RodsFeature`

If Jane were to bypass QA and merge `feature/JanesFeature` into `master`, there'd be no conflicts as `feature/RodsFeature` is not yet in `master`. However, Jane must merge into `QA` for obvious reasons. In order to resolve the conflict, she could pull and integrate Rod's changes into her feature branch, resolve the conflicts and then carry out the merge - with the undesirable consequence that once she merges her feature branch into `master` it'll also introduce Rod's changes which are still pending QA testing.

So - a workaround would be to resolve conflicts directly on the `QA` branch, leaving Jane's feature branch intact for later merging into `master`. However, this breaks code review policies, as merges should be approved by a peer - by doing this, she has merged into `QA` locally and pushed to remote without any pull request or peer review.

What would be considered 'best practice' in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Git Flow. It comes closest to what you're trying to accomplish.

Developers would branch their feature branch off the `qa` branch (called `develop` in Git Flow). complete their feature (regularly picking up the latest state of QA) and merge back to `develop` whenever possible (a feature is complete or it is in a stable state or it is turned off).

What you run as a `qa` branch would likely be the `release` branch in Gitflow.

Any change to master is immediately merged back to `develop`.

See also:

- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/

Comment: We had an issue with feature 1 and feature 2 being merged into QA branch but feature 1 being rejected and feature 2 being scheduled for immediate release. This issue was fixed by changing workflow to not merge features into QA / develop branch before they had been accepted!

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**: add a `dev` branch to do pull requests of specific 'task' branches with the changes for code reviews.

On some team projects I've been on there was also a `dev` branch to do "pull requests" on Github or some repository manager where a senior dev looks over what has changed and sees if that specific change is well-written etc.

In online repo host environments like Github, they have explicit ui showcasing the changes back to back with the original branch etc. After looking over a  branch, the senior dev then moves it into the Dev branch to ultimately be hosted in a qa environment to be looked over by the end of the sprint.